# Are "had served" and "had been serving" both acceptable in the situation?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

I have encountered this question in my test,
The model answer is "had been serving",
but I have written down "had served"

A)Mr.James had been serving this school for ten years when he retired from service.

B)Mr.James had served this school for ten years when he retired from service.

Is "had served" acceptable in the above situation?

Comment: Since the serving continued right up to the retirement ('when') the past perfect continuous aspect (in a single sentence) is proper. Many would consider the choice of the past perfect sub-optimal, and therefore consider it not the correct answer. One does hear the past perfect used in this sort of sentence ... but then one hears a lot of things.

Comment: Further to Edwin's comment...This probably better suited to English Learners, but the basic zombie rule for ESL students for writing complex sentences describing a past continuous action before an abrupt action interrupting it is to use a progressive construction + a simple past dependent clause headed with _when_.  i.e. progressive clause + when + simple past  clause. It’s not a real grammar rule; it’s just usage. Some people might say that it is grammatical.